# Importing a .csv/.dat info into MATLAB from an online data source in real-time/automatically?

Tags: arrays, file, matlab, download, real-time

I am trying to import real-time weather data from a weather station web link in to MATLAB directly and store it as a matrix which can be accessed. I don't have much experience with MATLAB but during my research I found similar queries.

This thread describes a similar situation extracting financial data from A URL to process in MATLAB:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/244112

Link to the raw data I require, containing the required comma separated info:
http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~weather/jcmb_ws/CR10X1.DAT

However, after re-arranging syntax I am not getting the desired result. Any tips?

I require the weather data to do a solar analysis on a PV array.

Answer (score 0):

use `csvread()` to read the CSV data and then use `save()` to save it as a MATRIX

Comment: Thanks for your response but how do I incorporate the hyperlink into csvread because isn't csvread() only usable to access local hard drive data? As I said I want it to be able to automatically pull updated data from the web link and update it in the storage matrix. Sorry if this is unclear, thank you in advance.

Comment: P.S I have applied urlread to extract data from http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~weather/jcmb_ws/JCMB_2013_Jan.csv

which is a saved CSV. It does so and tabulates it correctly. Would my problem be to do with the fact it is a .DAT file? read from that .dat file?